# i want to appear field stock and sales_price in PO

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9, odoo-11, odoo-12

inherit field (sale price, on hand, the unit price from product template to purchase order 
and it not com by its value in the product template
details in below image

[image]

Comment: Add more details and codes you tried to your question

Comment: How did you add the fields?

Answer (score 0):

```
@api.depends('product_qty', 'list_price', 'taxes_id','discount')
def _compute_amount(self):
    for line in self:
        taxes = line.taxes_id.compute_all(line.list_price, line.order_id.currency_id, line.product_qty, product=line.product_id, partner=line.order_id.partner_id)
        if line.discount:
            discount = (line.list_price * line.discount) / 100
            line.update({
                'price_tax': taxes['total_included'] - taxes['total_excluded'],
                'price_total': taxes['total_included'] ,
                'price_subtotal': taxes['total_excluded'] - discount,
                'price_unit': line.list_price - discount,
                'discount': (1 - (line.price_unite / line.list_price)) * 100,
            })
        else:
            line.update({
                'price_tax': taxes['total_included'] - taxes['total_excluded'],
                'price_total': taxes['total_included'],
                'price_subtotal': taxes['total_excluded'],
            })
```